# Laravel views doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm learning Laravel these days, and my routes don't show views !!

This is my code :

**web.php**

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/about','PagesController@about');
Route::get('/services','PagesController@services');
```

**PagesController**

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function about()
    {
        return view('pages.about');
    }

    public function services()
    {
        return view('pages.services');
    }
}
```

**about.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>{{config('app.name','LSAPP')}}</title>

    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>This is my About page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: I'm using kubunto with Lamp

Thank u guys for advance

Comment: What do you get instead ?? is there an error ?

Comment: when i try to reach **http://www.lsapp.dev/about** for exemple I recieve on my browser **This page isn’t working**

Comment: i guess the problem is with your apache? are you sure its running? and does home page works means only lsapp.dev??

Comment: do you have the blade saved on the pages folder ?

Comment: @Exprator yes it was working perfectly, but it stopped when I changed somehing on my tree project

Comment: Problem is most related with @Exprator's answer. Make sure that mod_rewrite is enable and your publilc folder has permission to override htacces rules.

Comment: Have you checked your php_error.log, laravel.log and your apache error.log?

Comment: @manix  it was working before but only with the home page

Comment: @RossWilson how can I do it ?

Comment: Your laravel.log should be `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Your php and apache error logs will be somewhere on your system. You should be able to use google by saying what server / system you're running and then php_error.log / apache error log. Please be aware that these files will probably have quite a lot of data in them, I would suggest deleting all the lines with in them and then refreshing the browser which should repopulate the logs with only the errors that are applicable.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>{{config('app.name','LSAPP')}}</title>
    <h1>About</h1>
</head>
<body>
 <p>This is my About page</p>
</body>
```

in your code i didn't find errors try to put `<p>` tag with in `body` tag... if doesn't work please share error what you'r getting..

Comment: I did it , it was just a mistake the problem is that I don't receive my view.  **This page isn’t working**  !!